# Changing a field from String to Int in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-integration

I am taking JSON information from our online API and producing it in a table with DI. I have 4 fields `url, deviceId, displacement & timestamp`. These are all recorded as Strings but I want them to be Int values, bar the `url`.

In the Generate Rows section I tried changing each parameter to an Int but the results would not show up but if I left them as Strings, it will post the results.

Any help on how I could change the data from type String to Int and still have my data reported?

Comment: I did....... 12 days ago!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take Select/Rename values Step, and change the data-type in meta-data section.

Comment: I'm going to use this as well.  What happens if there's a string accidentally in one of the rows?  How do you default if it's not a number?

Comment: @arcee123  You can use the step *script* or call any class of java and validate from there